# vertical scroll bar based on number of rows.js jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic table where rows and table are dynamically created. I have a scroll bar which is set using css. I was trying to show scroll bar when row > 2 using js but it did not work. I want to show scroll bar if row is greater than 2 please guide me to achieve this . for more information look at the code below(the code has 2 table is just for test only). any help will be highly appreciated

```js
//i want to display scroll bar based on number of rows if row >2 then display the scroll bar

//this is how i am adding row in my table

if ($('#testbody2 >tr').length > 2){
  $('#testbody2').css('overflow-y', 'visible');}
```

```css
.table1  th{
 border:2px solid black;

}

.table1 tbody{
 display:inline-block;
 
 max-height: 80px;       
    overflow-y: auto; 
}

.table2 tbody{
 display:block;
 
 height: 25px;       
    overflow-y: hidden; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>my first table</h3>
<div>
<table class="table1">
<thead>
<tr>test1</tr>
</thead>


<tbody id="testbody">
<tr><td>test</td></tr>
<tr><td>test</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>test</td></tr>

</tbody>
</table>

</div>


<h3>my second table</h3>
<div>
<table class="table2">
<thead>
<tr>test3</tr>
</thead>


<tbody id="testbody2">
<tr><td>test</td></tr>
<tr><td>test</td></tr>
</tr><td>testing</td></tr>
<tr><td>testing</td><tr>

<td>test</td></tr>

</tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your commented code you are missing the # to select an id.
This should work.

```
if ($('#testbody > tr').length > 2)
    $('#testbody').css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
```

Comment: You will need to set overflow-y: hidden; in your css, you will also need to set a height on the element.

Comment: I do not want to set height, is there anyway I can do it without setting height, just by number of rows?

Comment: So you want to display a scrollbar if there are more than 2 rows, what height would you expect the scrollable area to be? Either you allow it to be the height of all the items which means no scrollbar, or you set it to something to allow the scrollbar to show

Comment: Luke I did exactly what you said height:100px and scroll-y hidden in css and I used the exact code you have but scroll bar is not visible now. plss help

Comment: Well the height of all 3 of your tr elements is less than 100px so how about you try something smaller like 25px

Comment: Sorry, in your js code you will actually need $('#testbody').css('overflow-y', 'scroll'); not 'visible'

Comment: Luke awesome, working perfect. Thanks for great help.

Answer (score 1):

you need set the height of parent div and when rows are overflow then CSS worked

```
    .table1  th{
        border:2px solid black;

    }

    .table1 tbody{
        display:inline-block;

        max-height: 80px;       

    }

    #tb{
        display:block;

        height: 100px;       
         overflow-y: auto; 
    }


    #tb2{
        display:block;

        height: 100px;       
         overflow-y: auto; 
    }



    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <h3>my first table</h3>
    <div id="tb">
    <table class="table1">
    <thead>
    <tr>test1</tr>
    </thead>


    <tbody id="testbody">
    <tr><td>test</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test</td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td>test</td></tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>


    <h3>my second table</h3>
    <div id="tb2">
    <table class="table2">
    <thead>
    <tr>test3</tr>
    </thead>


    <tbody id="testbody2">
    <tr><td>test</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test</td></tr>
    </tr><td>testing</td></tr>
    <tr><td>testing</td><tr>

    <td>test</td></tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```